# long line not breaking into next step, it just keeps going. how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two paragraphs(commenting system and reply system) in my template, and they go without breaking into the next line. 
for instance, it should be four a in one line and four a in the other. but it goes aaaaaaaa. so when it's really long, it goes `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` in horizontal forever. 
is there css job for this or simple javascript so I can prevent this?

```
<div class="aboutComment">
    <span style="margin:5px;">
    {{ comment.get_comment }}</span> 
    </div>
```

Comment: You can add zero-width spaces to the text if it doesn't have visible spaces. A zero-width space looks like `\u200B` in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but are you looking for `word-wrap: break-word`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the CSS file:

```
.aboutComment{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: These are alternate names for each other. I have found it safest to add both, as some browsers use different settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word`:

```css
.aboutComment span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutComment">
  <span style="margin:5px;">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </span>
</div>
```